# Increate GPU quota on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

Does anyone know how to fix this issue where my `max_limit=0`, which renders me unable to set value higher than 0...
I think this happened after my trial period ended.

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qciHP.png)

Expected behavior:
Limit should be at least 1 so that I can set it to a value higher than 0.

Comment: Is it a personal project?

Answer (score 2):

You must request a GPU quota increase from Google. Requests are made using the Google Cloud Console GUI [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas).

See this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#gpu_quota) for more information on how to request a quota increase.